# Calling a function from a DLL which is developed in C++ from C

Tags: c++, c, dll

The function in dll has the prototype below

```
void Foo(int arg1, int& arg2);
```

The question is, how to declare the function prototype in C?

Is the declaration legal?

```
void Foo(int, int*);
```

Comment: Since the dll is made by 3rd party, I am afraid the function in dll can't be changed.

Comment: Then you need to write an "adapter DLL" **or** you have to embed this adapter in your program using this DLL.

Comment: Your code may be in C, but the question really is more about C++, I think

Comment: @StoryTeller it's about interfacing both, one of the rare cases both tags are appropriate ...

Comment: Thanks to both of you.   :)

Comment: Agreeing with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953401/calling-a-function-from-a-dll-which-is-developed-in-c#comment78864875_45953401) I rolled back the removal of the C tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the declaration legal?

It is, but it doesn't declare the same function. If you need a C API, you cannot use a reference. Stick to a pointer, and make sure the function has C linkage:

```
extern "C" void Foo(int, int*) {
   // Function body
}
```

If you cannot modify the DLL code, you need to write a C++ wrapper for it that exposes a proper C API.

Answer (score 5):

You need an adapter, consisting of a C++ translation unit and a header usable from both C and C++, like this (use better names of course):

**adapter.h:**

```
#ifndef ADAPTER_H
#define ADAPTER_H
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void adapter_Foo(int arg1, int *arg2);
// more wrapped functions

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**adapter.cpp:**

```
#include "adapter.h"
// includes for your C++ library here

void adapter_Foo(int arg1, int *arg2)
{
    // call your C++ function, e.g.
    Foo(arg1, *arg2);
}
```

You can compile this adapter into a separate DLL or you can have it as a part of your main program. In your C code, just `#include "adapter.h"` and call `adapter_Foo()` instead of `Foo()`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be closer if the C++ reference was represented as a `const` pointer in C?

Comment: @cdarke I don't think this matters much. making the pointer (as opposed to the data it points to) `const` only affects the code inside the function, and it's just a wrapper anyways...

Comment: @cdarke - `const` when applied to arguments in function declarations is ignored (you get the same declaration as if there was no `const`). At the definition, you can add it if you want the compiler to catch modifications. But like Felix said, I too think it's moot here.

Comment: Why not make the definition as accurate as possible?

Comment: @alk a `const` like in `int *const arg2` has no effect at all on the caller, so why bother? It's just unnecessary clutter.